# xpages search modulo inside a popup

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

With your help, I did create an Xpage with FTsearch & export into Excel features. The problem is  the search being made based on multiple input fields ( let say > 10 ) the xpage is heavy texted + considering the fact there is also a view panel where I list the search results once the Search button is clicked.

This is the main reason I've tried to create ( after the `link to Search&Export` is clicked ) some pop-up dialog ( which contains an xpage, I guess ) and this pop-up dialog to contain all my input fields + the 2 buttons already created: search & export. So, after I press the Search button from my pop-up => the pop-up dialog is closed and the search results are displayed in the view panel, same thing for the Excel button: pop-up is closed and I open the excel file.

Currently, when I click the `link to Search&Export` I 'see' all the input panel for the search ( all the input fields + the two buttons ) and of course the view panel. It does work but I think a pop-up dialog will be more user-friendly and it will give more space for the xpage.

What I want to do: move all the inputs fields + the `search` and `export to excel` buttons into a dialog, which should appear when the link is clicked.

How to create a dialog which opens when a link is clicked and contains this panel below ( where all the input fields and button for the FTsearch are contained there )

My code for the panel which contains the input fields and the search & export button:

```
<xp:panel style="background-color:rgb(242,242,242);border-color:rgb(168,168,168);border-width:thin;border-style:solid">
    <xp:table><xp:tr><xp:td><xp:label value="Din" id="label3" style="font-size:8pt;font-family:Verdana;color:rgb(128,0,0)">
                </xp:label></xp:td>
            <xp:td><xp:inputText id="inputText1" value="#{sessionScope.searchDate1}">
                    // some extra code
                </xp:label></xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="inputText2" value="#{sessionScope.searchDate2}">
                // some extra code
                </xp:inputText></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:label value="Author" id="label1"
                    style="font-size:8pt;font-family:Verdana;color:rgb(128,0,0)">
                </xp:label>
                </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="searchAutor"
                    value="#{sessionScope.searchAutor}">
                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td style="font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt">
                <xp:label id="label2" value="Titlu carte"
                    style="color:rgb(128,0,0);font-size:8pt;font-family:Verdana">
                </xp:label>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="searchTitlu"
                    value="#{sessionScope.searchTitlu}">
                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:button value="Search" id="button6"
                    styleClass="lotusFormButton">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true"
                        id="eventHandler1">
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
                    rendered="false">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "Query = " + sessionScope.queryString}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:text>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:button value="Export" id="button1"
                    styleClass="lotusFormButton" style="float:right;">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true"
                        id="eventHandler2">
                        <xp:this.action>
                            <xp:openPage
                                name="/export_hidden.xsp">
                            </xp:openPage>
                        </xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table></xp:panel>
```

I appreciate your time.

Comment: What is your specific question? How to create a dialog?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten How to create a dialog containing all my inputs and display it when the link is clicked

Comment: Put your dialog in a custom control, and create custom properties and pass them to the control.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I did already update my question with the code already created for the custom control which contains the input fields and the buttons for the FT search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of a dialog where you can add your fields to:

```
<xe:dialog id="exampleDialog" title="Example dialog">
    <xp:div styleClass="lotusDialogContent">
        <!-- Add your table here -->
    </xp:div>
    <div class="lotusDialogFooter">
        <!-- 
          add your buttons here
        -->

        <!-- example cancel link -->
        <xp:link id="link1" text="Cancel" styleClass="lotusAction">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog('#{id:exampleDialog}')]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:link>
    </div>
</xe:dialog>
```

You open the dialog using server-side JS like this:

```
getComponent("exampleDialog").show();
```

Or like this using client-side JS:

```
XSP.openDialog("#{id:exampleDialog}")
```

---

You can also style the content and button bar area entirely using extension library. Your dialog would then look like this:

```
<xe:dialog id="exampleDialog">
    <xe:dialogContent id="dialogContent1">
        <!-- content here -->
    </xe:dialogContent>
    <xe:dialogButtonBar id="dialogButtonBar1">
        <!-- buttons here -->
    </xe:dialogButtonBar>
</xe:dialog>
```

---

Here's an example of a button that you can use inside the dialog to close the dialog and refresh the viewpanel on the same XPage (assuming the viewpanel is called "viewpanel1"):

```
<xp:button value="Search" id="searchButton">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="false" refreshId="viewpanel1">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            getComponent('exampleDialog').hide()
        }]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

---

You can use XSP.addOnLoad() to open the dialog once the page is loaded. Add this to your XPage:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
        XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
            XSP.openDialog("#{id:exampleDialog}")
        });
    ]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Comment: thank you. The <xe:dialog> - should be declared into the source of the XPage where I show it using a link?

Comment: Or in a custom control that you add to the XPage.

Comment: I get "xe" element for "xe:dialog" is not bound.

Comment: Yes, because you didn't drag and drop the dialog control. So the XPages source XML does not know what xe is. Add xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" to the xp:view tag (or drag and drop an extension library control to your XPage)

Comment: thanks for your patience. My link code: facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("http://server/XB.nsf/search.xsp");
getComponent("exampleDialog").show(); ---> I go to that xpage but the dialog isn't shown.

Comment: Why go to another xpage and open the dialog there? Why not open the dialog directly on the page you start from?

Comment: The dialog I want is for the FTsearch modulo. So, I want first to go at that xpage where the viewpanel for the FTsearch results exist and after that open the dialog. After submitting the input fields I want the dialog closed and the search results to be displayed on that view panel from the search.xsp.

Comment: My answer gives you the code you need to create a dialog, and to open the dialog. I did not show you how to close the dialog as your button does a redirect to a new page. You should be able to use my answer to open the dialog from your xpage. Good luck.

Comment: OK, thanks for your suggestions, as my title question is clear, I will wait for other answers, before accept an eventually answer.

Comment: Now I understand. On the same XPage you want to be able to open the dialog, enter input values and hit the button inside the dialog which then should close the dialog and refresh your view. Let me update my question

Comment: Yes, exactly. The reason why I redirect firstly the facesContext is that I want to go on that XPages ( because when I click that link it is possible for me as a user to be at other Xpages in the app. ), and immediately open the dialog for the FTsearch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54904/discussion-between-mfg-flay-and-per-henrik-lausten).